# pip install editable succeeds, but package not importable (works witout --editable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pip

We need to `pip install -e` a python package from a private gitlab.  I can `pip3` install it over `ssh` to my `venv` and import/use successfully.  However, it's under active development so I need to install it `--editable`

When i add the `-e` to the install in my `requirements.txt`, the install still succeeds, but the package is no longer importable with the venv `activate`d.  How can I make this editable install functional?

In my `requirements.txt` (after install, `import asdf_logging` succeeds

```
# requirements.txt
git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git@v1.0.0#egg=asdf_logging&subdirectory=python-pkg
```

details from the install:

```
# during the `pip install -r ...` :
Collecting asdf_logging
  Cloning ssh://****@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git (to revision v1.0.0) to /tmp/pip-install-pepvvw3o/asdf-logging
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git' /tmp/pip-install-pepvvw3o/asdf-logging
  Running command git checkout -q deadbeef

# `find . -name 'asdf*logging*'` prints
./py-venv-tooling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asdf_logging
./py-venv-tooling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asdf_logging-1.0.0.dist-info
```

but changing (deleting/reinstalling the venv) to results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asdf_logging'`

```
# requirements.txt
 -e   git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git@v1.0.0#egg=asdf_logging&subdirectory=python-pkg
#^^^
```

details from the install

```
# during the `pip install -r ...`, this time with '-e' :
Obtaining asdf_logging from git+ssh://****@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git@v1.0.0#egg=asdf_logging&subdirectory=python-pkg (from -r /home/me/repo/py-requirements-tooling.txt (line 46))
  Cloning ssh://****@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git (to revision v1.0.0) to ./py-venv-tooling/src/asdf-logging
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@gitlab.com/asdf/product/libraries/asdf-logging.git' /home/me/repo/py-venv-tooling/src/asdf-logging

# `find . -name 'asdf*logging*'` prints:
./py-venv-tooling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asdf-logging.egg-link
./py-venv-tooling/src/asdf-logging
./py-venv-tooling/src/asdf-logging/python-pkg/src/asdf_logging
./py-venv-tooling/src/asdf-logging/python-pkg/asdf_logging.egg-info

# ll ./py-venv-tooling/lib/python3.8/site-packages | grep asdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me     115 May 17 20:30 asdf-logging.egg-link

# cat ./py-venv-tooling/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/-theCorrectAbsPathToParent-/py-venv-tooling/src/asdf-logging/python-pkg
# with `ls -al` on this ^^^ path:
drwxrwxr-x 1 me me 104 May 18 10:46 asdf_logging.egg-info   # <-- dependency_links.txt  PKG-INFO  SOURCES.txt  top_level.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 504 May 18 10:46 setup.py
drwxrwxr-x 1 me me  30 May 18 10:46 src
```

the git repo is as follows:

```
# tree
.
├── .git
├── python-pkg
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── src
│       └── asdf_logging
│           ├── configure_logging.py
│           ├── __init__.py
        ...
└── README.md
```

and `setup.py` (again, WORKING if i do not use `--editable`)

```
setup(
    name="asdf-logging",
    description="...",
    version="1.0.0",
    # packages=find_packages(exclude=["test_*"]),
    packages=["asdf_logging"],
    package_dir={"asdf_logging": "src/asdf_logging"},
    author_email="me@asdf.com"
    )
```

the code is checked out where i'd expect in ~`venv/src`, and the `.egg-link` has a path that to the parent of `/src`, as dumped above

Comment: "*…shouldn't there be symlinks to that from `site-packages`?*" No, the file `site-packages/asdf-logging.egg-link` is the link that makes Python to know where from to import the package.

Comment: @phd - question updated with this, thank you.  The link in `egg-link` points to `python-pkg` (contains `setup.py`, parent of `src/`).